# I can't login to chat.stackexchange anymore

Tags: bug, chat, stack-exchange, login, openid

When I try to go to chat.stackexchange. I get this:
[image: picture when I use latest Opera for linux x86-64]
As you can see, I don't have the option to click on *"log in using Google"* anymore like on other stackexchanges sites:
[image: Picture from SuperUser]
I don't think this is a browser related problem, as global login append automatically when I use the same browser version on 64-bits Windows. **Nothing would be a problem If I don't have to click ***"log in via Stack Exchange."*
I went on https://chat.stackexchange.com/help and I got :
[image: screeshot of]
When I click on *"log in via Stack Exchange."* or I load [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login) I just get that :
[image: I don't have any idea on which is the setting I need to change]
I know other people may have the same problem, but the current other answers don't let me use [chat.stackexchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Check again, mine were all green

Comment: Are you using HTTPSAnywhere?  That broke logging into chat for me earlier today.

Comment: @Joe : [Traffic Analysis](http://cryptome.org/2014/03/https-ta.pdf). No I don't have any extensions installed. I prefer Opera Widgets. LOOK at THE SCREENSHOTS!

Comment: Maybe try other browser?

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Know FireFox send more informations than Google-chrome. I'm feeling concerned by "[shadow-scoring](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipédia:Oracle#Recherche_d.27entreprises_sur_le_.2F_.CA.83ad..C9.99.CA.8A.CB.88sk.C9.92.CB.90r.C9.AA.C5.8Bg_.2F)". And look at the screenshots : Opera 12.50 have many unique features, such tab content preview *(see last image)*. You can also create tab directories, and dynamically expand them. You can also save/restore tabs to files... I also tried the same version again on windows at school this morning : **It work**.

Comment: @user2284570 I'm not saying Opera is not good, it might be the best browser ever. But it does not mean all web sites will fully support it. Plus, this is obviously problem at your end as thousands of other users can login to chat.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Again, I've no problem with the same version, but on 64-bits windows.